# Using PHPass to hash passwords in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpass

Just want to use [PHPass](http://www.openwall.com/phpass/) in Codeigniter to hash the password. I downloaded the zip file from phpass website, extracted the content, and copied the PasswordHash.php file into my libraries folder.

Then I loaded that library in my controller and tried to hash password but it gave following errors

```
Missing argument 1 for PasswordHash::PasswordHash(), called in ...
Missing argument 2 for PasswordHash::PasswordHash(), called in ...
Undefined variable: iteration_count_log2 ...
Undefined variable: portable_hashes ...
```

Please check my controller code below and help me to find the mistake:

```
$this->load->library('PasswordHash');
$password = $this->input->post('password');
$hash = $this->passwordhash->HashPassword( $password );
```

Comment: Please provide more info

Comment: please specify which type of info you need. I provided the code and frameworks I use and the errors which I get.

Comment: why not you use md5() function for converting password into hash, instead of like this?

Comment: this is a more secure way

Comment: don't use md5 function it is insecure and susceptible to rainbow table attack. using phpass is the correct way to hash password since it takes care of salting and stretching

Comment: @HamzaZafeer Please don't suggest crap, terrible and insecure practices to innocent readers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's how i do it. first create it as a helper.

```
<?php (defined('BASEPATH')) OR exit('No direct script access allowed');
#
# Portable PHP password hashing framework.
#
# Version 0.3 / genuine.
#
# Written by Solar Designer <solar at openwall.com> in 2004-2006 and placed in
# the public domain.  Revised in subsequent years, still public domain.
#
# There's absolutely no warranty.
#
# The homepage URL for this framework is:
#
#   http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
#
# Please be sure to update the Version line if you edit this file in any way.
# It is suggested that you leave the main version number intact, but indicate
# your project name (after the slash) and add your own revision information.
#
# Please do not change the "private" password hashing method implemented in
# here, thereby making your hashes incompatible.  However, if you must, please
# change the hash type identifier (the "$P$") to something different.
#
# Obviously, since this code is in the public domain, the above are not
# requirements (there can be none), but merely suggestions.
#
class PasswordHash {
    var $itoa64;
    var $iteration_count_log2;
    var $portable_hashes;
    var $random_state;

    function PasswordHash($iteration_count_log2, $portable_hashes)
    {
        $this->itoa64 = './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';

        if ($iteration_count_log2 < 4 || $iteration_count_log2 > 31)
            $iteration_count_log2 = 8;
        $this->iteration_count_log2 = $iteration_count_log2;

        $this->portable_hashes = $portable_hashes;

        $this->random_state = microtime();
        if (function_exists('getmypid'))
            $this->random_state .= getmypid();
    }

    function get_random_bytes($count)
    {
        $output = '';
        if (is_readable('/dev/urandom') &&
            ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb'))) {
            $output = fread($fh, $count);
            fclose($fh);
        }

        if (strlen($output) < $count) {
            $output = '';
            for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i += 16) {
                $this->random_state =
                    md5(microtime() . $this->random_state);
                $output .=
                    pack('H*', md5($this->random_state));
            }
            $output = substr($output, 0, $count);
        }

        return $output;
    }

    function encode64($input, $count)
    {
        $output = '';
        $i = 0;
        do {
            $value = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $this->itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            if ($i < $count)
                $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
            if ($i++ >= $count)
                break;
            $output .= $this->itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
        } while ($i < $count);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_private($input)
    {
        $output = '$P$';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[min($this->iteration_count_log2 +
            ((PHP_VERSION >= '5') ? 5 : 3), 30)];
        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 6);

        return $output;
    }

    function crypt_private($password, $setting)
    {
        $output = '*0';
        if (substr($setting, 0, 2) == $output)
            $output = '*1';

        $id = substr($setting, 0, 3);
        # We use "$P$", phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing
        if ($id != '$P$' && $id != '$H$')
            return $output;

        $count_log2 = strpos($this->itoa64, $setting[3]);
        if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30)
            return $output;

        $count = 1 << $count_log2;

        $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
        if (strlen($salt) != 8)
            return $output;

        # We're kind of forced to use MD5 here since it's the only
        # cryptographic primitive available in all versions of PHP
        # currently in use.  To implement our own low-level crypto
        # in PHP would result in much worse performance and
        # consequently in lower iteration counts and hashes that are
        # quicker to crack (by non-PHP code).
        if (PHP_VERSION >= '5') {
            $hash = md5($salt . $password, TRUE);
            do {
                $hash = md5($hash . $password, TRUE);
            } while (--$count);
        } else {
            $hash = pack('H*', md5($salt . $password));
            do {
                $hash = pack('H*', md5($hash . $password));
            } while (--$count);
        }

        $output = substr($setting, 0, 12);
        $output .= $this->encode64($hash, 16);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_extended($input)
    {
        $count_log2 = min($this->iteration_count_log2 + 8, 24);
        # This should be odd to not reveal weak DES keys, and the
        # maximum valid value is (2**24 - 1) which is odd anyway.
        $count = (1 << $count_log2) - 1;

        $output = '_';
        $output .= $this->itoa64[$count & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 6) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 12) & 0x3f];
        $output .= $this->itoa64[($count >> 18) & 0x3f];

        $output .= $this->encode64($input, 3);

        return $output;
    }

    function gensalt_blowfish($input)
    {
        # This one needs to use a different order of characters and a
        # different encoding scheme from the one in encode64() above.
        # We care because the last character in our encoded string will
        # only represent 2 bits.  While two known implementations of
        # bcrypt will happily accept and correct a salt string which
        # has the 4 unused bits set to non-zero, we do not want to take
        # chances and we also do not want to waste an additional byte
        # of entropy.
        $itoa64 = './ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789';

        $output = '$2a$';
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 / 10);
        $output .= chr(ord('0') + $this->iteration_count_log2 % 10);
        $output .= '$';

        $i = 0;
        do {
            $c1 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1 >> 2];
            $c1 = ($c1 & 0x03) << 4;
            if ($i >= 16) {
                $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
                break;
            }

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 4;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $c1 = ($c2 & 0x0f) << 2;

            $c2 = ord($input[$i++]);
            $c1 |= $c2 >> 6;
            $output .= $itoa64[$c1];
            $output .= $itoa64[$c2 & 0x3f];
        } while (1);

        return $output;
    }

    function HashPassword($password)
    {
        $random = '';

        if (CRYPT_BLOWFISH == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(16);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_blowfish($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 60)
                return $hash;
        }

        if (CRYPT_EXT_DES == 1 && !$this->portable_hashes) {
            if (strlen($random) < 3)
                $random = $this->get_random_bytes(3);
            $hash =
                crypt($password, $this->gensalt_extended($random));
            if (strlen($hash) == 20)
                return $hash;
        }

        if (strlen($random) < 6)
            $random = $this->get_random_bytes(6);
        $hash =
            $this->crypt_private($password,
            $this->gensalt_private($random));
        if (strlen($hash) == 34)
            return $hash;

        # Returning '*' on error is safe here, but would _not_ be safe
        # in a crypt(3)-like function used _both_ for generating new
        # hashes and for validating passwords against existing hashes.
        return '*';
    }

    function CheckPassword($password, $stored_hash)
    {
        $hash = $this->crypt_private($password, $stored_hash);
        if ($hash[0] == '*')
            $hash = crypt($password, $stored_hash);

        return $hash == $stored_hash;
    }
}

/* End of file phpass_helper.php */
/* Location: ./application/helpers/phpass_helper.php */
```

to use the phpass helper, load the helper, instantiate it, call HashPassword function:

```
    $this->load->helper('phpass');
    $hasher = new PasswordHash(PHPASS_HASH_STRENGTH, PHPASS_HASH_PORTABLE);
    $hash_password = $hasher->HashPassword($password);
```

in config/constants.php add the following code:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Portable PHP password hashing framework
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| 
| http://www.openwall.com/phpass/
|
*/
define('PHPASS_HASH_STRENGTH', 8);
define('PHPASS_HASH_PORTABLE', FALSE);
```

You should also now understand why you getting the error about missing argument 1 and 2.
When you instantiate the PasswordHash class you need to supply two arguments to it.
You can create phpass as a CodeIgniter Library file too. Just change the function PasswordHash to __constructor and when calling the library supply two arguments. i'll leave you to figure that out.

Comment: Thank you very much :) As I understood, phpass uses salt but no need to store salt in database. All I need is store hashed password, right? If yes, could you please tell me which length varchar I should use for storing hashed password.

Comment: I also found out a strange fact that the hashed version of same word can be different each time. So how I can organize login validation?

Comment: It seems validation should be done using the following line $hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash)

Comment: the same password is hash differently each time because of the salt. the salt is stored in the same string along with the password.

Comment: i use varchar(60) to store the password hashes. im not 100% sure if shorter would work, it might. but 60 definitely works.

Comment: Is there any javascript version of this code? because I used it in my php application and now I change my application to Nodejs. So the users registered with PHP application should be able to login to the new Nodejs application.

Answer (score 3):

If you're running PHP 5.5 or higher, I strongly suggest using PHP's built-in [password hashing functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.password.php). IMHO these eliminate the need for any third party/self-written hashers.

As an added bonus you can easily switch hashing algorithms when you specify a specific algorithm, or when PHP changes its default algorithm. Assuming you are ok with PHP's defaults (random salted, CRYPT_BLOWFISH with an algorithmic cost of 10) the following code gives you an idea of how it works.

To create a hash for storage in you database you use the result of

```
password_hash($newPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

And when you check the password, you immediately check if you need to rehash the password like so:

```
if (password_verify($userInput, $storedHash)) {
    // The password provided by the user in $userInput
    // matches the hash we stored (in a database) $storedHash

    if(password_needs_rehash($storedHash, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)) {
         $newHash = password_hash($userInput, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

         // store new hash in database here
    }

    // your what-to-do-on-login-code here

} else {

   // your what-to-do-on-login-failure-code here

}
```

Nice and clean, huh?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will use your answer when I will start to use php 5.5 or higher. Actually, I use codeigniter and as I know it does not support php 5.5 yet.

Comment: @EducateYourself Use the compatibility library for lower PHP versions https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat

Answer (score 0):

Before we start integrating PHPass in your CodeIgniter Project, download the PHPass from this link:
http://carlofontanos.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/phppass.rar

Go to application/config/autoload.php then locate the code:

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array();
```

Then add the phpass library so that it gets autoloaded every time CodeIgniter is accessed.

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('phppass/passwordhash');
```

If you do not want to autoload PHPass then you can construct the library in your Model or Controller like this:

```
$this->load->library('phppass/passwordhash');
```

PasswordHash class adds salt to the password and hashes it with 8 passes of MD5. MD5 is used by default because it’s supported on all platforms.

To generate a password and to compare passwords, continue reading on this link:
http://carlofontanos.com/using-phpass-library-in-codeigniter/